# ProcessThreads' TotalProcessorTime does not match Process's

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi

I was currently trying to monitor the performance of my project. When I enumerated all physical threads (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads) the sum of total time spent on processor was much much lower than the total processor time on the process itself. The number of threads was stable, there were almost no threads that I could miss (maybe some until I opened the monitoring window). Why is that?

I had also problem with InvalidOperationException: the thread already exited (when I read the TotalProcessorTime). However, when I looked for the thread's state, it was Waiting. How can I evade the exception?

Thanks

Comment: Any threads which have terminated will not be included in your enumerations, but their processor usage contributes to the total process count.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I start the monitoring right after application start, so I doubt tasks terminated before I start to monitor them would cause such huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of threads created and distroyed by the .Net framework and Operating system which you have no control over.

The Garbage Collector for example can use multiple threads. When you call into Win32 API's (the .Net framework may do this for you) these can also fire off short lived threads.

Comment: You say that Process.Threads does not contain all underlying threads? I know I have no control over the threads, ProcessThread just gives some info. From MSDN: "Use ProcessThread to get all the threads associated with the current process."
If you're right: can the WinAPI show me all threads?

Comment: Short-lived threads are possible explanation, but it seems weird to me that I never catch any of them. Moreover, the app is running some heavy-computation managed Threads and I would be wondering if OS spawned physical threads every second and relocated the logical thread.